# Display pixel color from .pgm image file in C

Tags: c, image

I am writing a program where in I need to display image in .pgm format to TFT screen. I am using C language. I am able to read the file and when I tried to display image content on screen, I can see only characters coming and not the pixel color. I am using P5 magic number in .pgm file. My question is simple how this character (in .pgm file) can be displayed as a pixel color? Should I have to use any library functions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need a graphics library that works with ANSI C like [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) and [Allegro](http://www.liballeg.org/)